# Definition of reducible lattice

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups, topological-groups, lattices, arithmetic-groups

I am reading Raghunathan's [book](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642864285) on discrete subgroups of Lie groups.

In particular I am stuck on Corollary 5.19 which gives several equivalent conditions for a lattice in a semisimple Lie group to be reducible.

Recall that a lattice $\Gamma$ in a Lie group $G$ is a discrete subgroup of fintie covolume.

The result I do not understand reads as follows:

Corollary 5.19: Let $G$ be a connected semisimple Lie group without compact factors. Let $H$, $H^{\prime}$ be connected closed proper normal subgroups of $G$ such that $HH^{\prime}=G$, and $H\cap H^{\prime}$ is discrete in $G$. Let $\pi$ (resp. $\pi^{\prime}$) be the natural projection maps of $G\to G/H^{\prime}$ (resp. $G/H$). Let $\Gamma\subset G$ be a lattice then the following are equivalent:

1) $\pi(\Gamma)$ is a discrete subgroup of $G/H^{\prime}$

2)$\pi^{\prime}(\Gamma)$ is a discrete subgroup of $G/H$

3) $\Gamma\cap H$ is a lattice in $H$

4) $\Gamma\cap H^{\prime}$ is a lattice in $H^{\prime}$

There are three more equivalent conditions also but I understand the implications of those as they are spelled out in detail.

What I do not understand are the implications $1) \iff 4)$ and $2) \iff 3)$. What I do understand is that the proofs will be identical.

The book says the following in regards to the proof:

``The implications $1) \iff 4)$ and $2) \iff 3)$ are simply restatements of Theorem 1.13''.

Theorem 1.13 reads:

Theorem 1.13: Let $G$ be a second countable locally compact group and $\Gamma$ a lattice in $G$. Let $H$ be a closed subgroup. Then if $H\cap\Gamma$ is a lattice in $H$, $H\Gamma$ is closed in $G$; equivalently the natural injection

$H/(H\cap \Gamma)\to G/\Gamma$

is proper. Futhermore, if $H$ is normal in $G$ or if $\Gamma$ is uniform (i.e. $G/\Gamma$ is compact), then $H\Gamma$ is closed in $G$ if and only if $H\cap\Gamma$ is a lattice in $H$.

Recall a map is proper if the preimage of compact sets is compact.

I understand Theorem 1.13 and its proof perfectly.

However I cannot see how the mapping $H/H\cap \Gamma\to G/\Gamma$ being proper should imply that the projection $\pi(\Gamma)$ of a lattice is discrete in $G/H^{\prime}$ (and vice versa), similarly for $\pi^{\prime}(\Gamma)$ in $G/H$?

How do compact sets become relevant?

Why should the image of a discrete set stay discrete?

This has been crossposted from [stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3553631/definition-of-reducible-lattice).

Comment: The corollary is false as stated. You need to assume normality of $H,H'$.

Comment: @UriBader edited to account for this, thanks